# detect changes in a component property -Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component in which you set the following properties using buttons :

```
dataType:String = null
 fechaI : Date = null
 fechaF :Date = null
 checkedList =[]
```

i want to run an http request whenever all the properties have values and be able to redo the request  if any of those change value during runtime

I tried the following with doCheck

```
ngDoCheck(){
    if((this.checkedList !=null)&&(this.dataType!=null)&&(this.fechaI !=null)&&(this.fechaF !=null)){
      console.table(this.checkedList)
      console.log(this.dataType)
      console.log(this.fechaF)
      console.log('ENVIO DE OPCIONES')
      this.http.post('',{})
  }
}
```

BUT everytime i scroll or do anything the hook for doCheck gets triggered , so its not a viable option for me.How would i be able to achieve the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

If You're trying to detect changes from variables of your controller you should go for this path:

The best way to use change detection in your case is creating a single object from your your variables, like this:

```
myObj = {
  dataType: null
  fechaI: null
  fechaF: null
  checkedList: []
}
```

And then in the view:

```
<input type="text"  
  [ngModel]="myObj.dataType"
  (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"
  name="dataType"
  required>
```

The detection:

```
onChange($changes) {
  console.log($changes)
  this.http.post(myUrl, $changes) // Pretend
}
```

Comment: doesnt this only apply to Parent-Child components? doesnt seem to trigger when i use it in the same component even following the documentation